# Adding HTML element in Kendo UI Grid row?

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have some grid that is going from JSON here is example of my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var orders = [{
  OrderID : 10248,
  CustomerID : "<i class='fa fa-car'></i>",
  EmployeeID : 5,
  OrderDate : new Date(1996, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  RequiredDate : new Date(1996, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  ShippedDate : new Date(1996, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  ShipVia : 3,
  Freight : 32.3800,
  ShipName : "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
  ShipAddress : "59 rue de l'Abbaye",
  ShipCity : "Reims",
  ShipRegion : "",
  ShipPostalCode : "51100",
  ShipCountry : "<i class='fa fa-car'></i>"
}, {
  OrderID : 10249,
  CustomerID : "TOMSP",
  EmployeeID : 6,
  OrderDate : new Date(1996, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  RequiredDate : new Date(1996, 7, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  ShippedDate : new Date(1996, 6, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  ShipVia : 1,
  Freight : 11.6100,
  ShipName : "Toms SpezialitГ¤ten",
  ShipAddress : "Luisenstr. 48",
  ShipCity : "MГјnster",
  ShipRegion : "",
  ShipPostalCode : "44087",
  ShipCountry : "Germany"
},  {
  OrderID : 11077,
  CustomerID : "RATTC",
  EmployeeID : 1,
  OrderDate : new Date(1998, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  RequiredDate : new Date(1998, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  ShippedDate : null,
  ShipVia : 2,
  Freight : 8.5300,
  ShipName : "Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery",
  ShipAddress : "2817 Milton Dr.",
  ShipCity : "Albuquerque",
  ShipRegion : "NM",
  ShipPostalCode : "87110",
  ShipCountry : "USA"
}];


$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: orders,
      pageSize: 7,
      resizable: true,
    },
    sortable: {
      mode: "single",
      allowUnsort: false
    },
    selectable: "multiple",
    pageable: {
      buttonCount: 5
    },
    scrollable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    columns: [
      {
        field: "ShipCountry",
        title: "Ship Country" ,
        width: 200
      },
      {
        field: "Freight",
        width: 200
      },
      {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

I got something like this
[image]

That is ok, but what I need I have to add an image in the cell and change color, here is a picture of what I need?

This is just an example, I need to add some mine HTML tag in that cell?

[image]

I know I can do it just bind table, but that way I don't get pagination on table?

Here is what I have used to bind
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/index.html

only how to add custom HTML in table, with pagination?

Answer (score 1):

If you want HTML to be rendered in a column, you have to turn off `encoding`.

> If set to true the column value will be HTML-encoded before it is displayed. If set to false the column value will be displayed as-is. By default the column value is HTML-encoded.

From the [Kendo Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.encoded)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rowSelection").kendoGrid({
    //...
    columns: [
      {
        field: "ShipCountry",
        encoded: false
      }
    ]
  });
});
```